# Google Sheets Add Number Increment Column To Query Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a query that is pulling out and ordering two columns

```
=QUERY(Registration!$E$7:$F240, "Select E,F Order by F, E")
```

I would like an automatic column before the two with a number increment
1,2,3....

Is this possible?
I may just not be searching for how with the proper terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
  QUERY(Registration!$E$7:$F240, "select E Order by F"))))), 
  QUERY(Registration!$E$7:$F240, "select E,F where E is not null order by F,E")}
```

[image: 0]